# Subtract value from class instance attribute

Tags: python, class

Basic question. Say I have the class:

```
@dataclass
class Person:
   
    moneyInTheBank: float
```

And i want to implement that when I do something like:

```
Person(100) - 10
```

I get

```
Person(moneyInTheBank = 90)
```

How is that done easily? Magic Methods? Getters and Setters?

Comment: Add a method to subtract the amount specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `__sub__` magic method:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Person:
    moneyInTheBank: float

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return Person(self.moneyInTheBank - other)

p = Person(100)
print(p - 10)
```

Prints:

```py
Person(moneyInTheBank=90.0)
```

EDIT:
If you want to modify the object, try using this:

```py
def __sub__(self, other):
    self.moneyInTheBank -= other
    return self
```

To make it work with `-=`, use `__isub__`

Comment: This will return a new instance of a Person class which may be what's required but returning *self* (after performing the calculation) may be more appropriate

Comment: I edited the answer to include returning self.

Comment: The edited answer was what I was looking for. I don't get the last remark. It also works as suggested with ```__sub__```.